# a question about this python script!

Tags: python

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    fname= raw_input("Please enter your file:")
    mTrue=1
    Salaries=''
    Salarieslist={}
    Employeesdept=''
    Employeesdeptlist={}
    try:
        f1=open(fname)
    except:
        mTrue=0
        print 'The %s does not exist!'%fname
    if mTrue==1:
        ss=[]   
        for x in f1.readlines():
            if 'Salaries' in x:
                Salaries=x.strip()
            elif 'Employees' in x:
                Employeesdept=x.strip()
        f1.close()
        if Salaries and Employeesdept:
            Salaries=Salaries.split('-')[1].strip().split(' ')
            for d in Salaries:
                s=d.strip().split(':')
                Salarieslist[s[0]]=s[1]
            Employeesdept=Employeesdept.split('-')[1].strip().split(' ')
            for d in Employeesdept:
                s=d.strip().split(':')
                Employeesdeptlist[s[0]]=s[1]
            print "1) what is the average salary in the company: %s "%Salarieslist['Avg']            
            print "2) what are the maximum and minimum salaries in the company: maximum:%s,minimum:%s "%(Salarieslist['Max'],Salarieslist['Min'])
            print "3) How many employees are there in each department :IT:%s, Development:%s, Administration:%s"%(
                Employeesdeptlist['IT'],Employeesdeptlist['Development'],Employeesdeptlist['Administration'])


        else:
            print 'The %s data is err!'%fname
```

When I enter a filename, but it didn't continue, why? If I enter a file named company.txt, but it always show the file does not exist. why?

Comment: Because it doesn't? At least not in the working directory.

Answer (score 4):

I can give you some hints which can help you to resolve problem better

Create a function and call it in main e.g.

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Don't put whole block under `if mTrue==1:` instead just return from function on error e.g.

```
def main():
    fname= raw_input("Please enter your file:")
    try:
        f1=open(fname)
    except:
        print 'The %s does not exist!'%fname
        return

    ... # main code here
```

Never catch all exceptions , instead catch specific exception e.g. IOError

```
try:
   f1 = open(fname):
except IOError,e:
  print 'The %s does not exist!'%fname
```

otherwise catching all exception may catch syntax error or mis-spelled names etc

Print the exception you are getting, it may not always be file not found, may be you don't have read permission or something like that

and finally your problem could be just that, file may not exist, try to input full path

Answer (score 1):

Your current working directory does not contain `company.txt`.
Either set your current working directory or use an absolute path.

You can change the working directory like so:

```
import os
os.chdir(new_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to be more specific about which exceptions you want to catch you should considered capturing the exception object itself so you can print a string representation of it as part of your error message:

```
try:
    f1 = open(fname, 'r')
except IOError, e:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Some error occurred while trying to open %s" % fname
    print >> sys.stderr, e
```

(You can also learn more about specific types of Exception objects and perhaps handle
some sorts of exceptions in your code.  You can even capture Exceptions for your own inspection from within the interpreter so you can run `dir()` on them, and `type()` on each of the interesting attributes you find ... and so on.